# Share AngularJS URI in Facebook

Tags: facebook, angularjs, uri, share

I want to share this AngularJS URI:

http://blog.pabloleone.com/#/posts/migrar-galeria-de-imagenes-de-wordpress

in Facebook. I use this link

http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://blog.pabloleone.com/#/posts/migrar-galeria-de-imagenes-de-wordpress

This does not work.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use encoded string:

encodeURIComponent("http://blog.pabloleone.com/#/posts/migrar-galeria-de-imagenes-de-wordpress")

http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.pabloleone.com%2F%23%2Fposts%2Fmigrar-galeria-de-imagenes-de-wordpress